# Swift Full Text Search Recommended Solution

Tags: ios, swift, full-text-search, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering if there was a recommended solution/library in `Swift` for integrating full text search (i.e. search bar that filters on presented data as you type, autocomplete)?

I am currently using `Firestore` as my backend.

Something I've glanced on is `Algolia`?

Comment: Did you end up finding a cost-effective solution?  Algolia looks feature rich but it’s too expensive...  In my case, expensive because of the record limits

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSPredicate` to search the text inside your objects, like this

```
let searchString = "test"
var arr:NSArray =
    [["value" : "its a test text to find"],
     ["value" : "another text"],
     ["value" : "find this text"],
     ["value" : "lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly"],
     ["value" : "lorem ipsum is a"]]


var pre:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "value CONTAINS[c] %@", searchString)
var result:NSArray = arr.filtered(using: pre) as NSArray

print(result)
```

it will return a array with the result based on the text that you search

Answer (score 1):

Algolia is probably the best solution right now, and is something Firebase themselves recommend. Just a few things to bear in mind is that you'll need a paid for Firebase plan to implement as you'll need a Cloud Function that sends data over to Algolia for indexing.

Once your data is in Algolia there is a great [Swift library](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-swift) you can use to implement the Search Bars / Autocompletion you need.